# const object in c++

Tags: c++, constants

I have a question on constant objects. In the following program:

```
class const_check{
    int a;
    public:
    const_check(int i);
    void print() const;
    void print2();
};

const_check::const_check(int i):a(i) {}

void const_check::print() const {
int a=19;
    cout<<"The value in a is:"<<a;
}

void const_check::print2() {
    int a=10;
    cout<<"The value in a is:"<<a;
}

int main(){
    const_check b(5);
    const const_check c(6);
    b.print2();
    c.print();
}
```

`void print()` is a constant member function of the class `const_check`, so according to the definition of constants any attempt to change `int a` should result in an error, but the program works fine for me. I think I am having some confusion here, can anybody tell me why the compiler is not flagging it as an error?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

By writing

```
int a = 19;
```

inside `print()`, you are declaring a new local variable `a`. This has nothing to do with the `int a` that you declared inside the class `const_check`. The member variable is said to be *shadowed* by the local variable. And it's perfectly okay to declare local variables in a `const` function and modify them; the `const`ness only applies to the fields of the object.

Try writing

```
a = 19;
```

instead, and see an error appear.

Comment: Oh i missed that...Silly Thanks

Comment: At least when using gcc, you may switch on a warning for this situation: `-Wshadow` will gcc make raising warnings when a symbol shadows another. IMO it's a good thing to switch on a lot of these warnings, so that you do not run into unintended behaviour, like this one.
I bet clang and other compilers do have a comparable command line flag.

Answer (score 4):

You aren't changing the instance variable `a` you are creating a local variable `a` in each method.

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing the member variable a in either print() or print2(). You're declaring a new local variable a which shadows the member variable a.

Answer (score -3):

Also, unless I am mistaken, you forgot to actually declare the member variable const to begin with.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it. When a member function is const, that means that the this pointer is a const pointer to const, so you can't modify it or anything it points to - that includes member variables of that object (and even if you don't explicitly use this, you're always using it when accessing member variables from within a member function). If a member variable is const, then you can't modify it at all - even in a non-const member function. But in a const member function, you can't modify any member variables regardless of whether it's const or not.

Comment: You're right - I missed that he declared the method const instead.